# Convert array to an array object with some modifications

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

i'm pretty beginner in the JavaScript and I really need help to convert an array to an array object. There are many examples here in stackOverflow, but I need some modidfication during this process, which is why I couldn't do anything

For example I have:

```
data = [{id: 21, name: "jack"} , {id: 185, name: "yas"}]
```

and I need to convert it with something like that (id key change to student_id, and present = true, should be added), and the length of this array is dynamic and will change over time.

```
[
  {
    "student_id" : 21,
    "present" = true
   },
   {
    "student_id" : 185,
    "present" = true
   }  
]
```

I need to add these array object to:

```
 const data: any = { 
    here....
  };
```

your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Your example `data` is not a valid JavaScript data structure. Arrays do not have _keys_

Comment: can you check it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data actually looks more like this

```js
data = [{id: 21, name: "jack"}, {id: 185, name: "yas"}]
```

This is a simple matter of [*mapping*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the array to a new format with the properties you want

```js
const data = [{id: 21, name: "jack"}, {id: 185, name: "yas"}]

const newData = data.map(({ id }) => ({
  student_id: id,
  present: true
}))

console.log(newData)
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough, after a tough day, you saved me. Thanks